# CSS Z-indexing anomaly

Tags: html, css

I am getting a strange anomaly with my z-indexing. I have an image which I positioned relative with a z-index of 1, and that sits above my navigation which is positioned absolute and has a z-index of -1.

The issue is that on page load the image is behind the navigation until you scroll down and back up again, then it corrects it self and sits above the navigation as it should.

Any ideas on what might cause this?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: The greater the z-index , the higher the Element!

Answer (score 0):

Only set the z-index on the item you want to be ON TOP of everything else. Every element has a default z-index, so you don't need to set it on your nav menu. Just set the z-index on your image to something like 999999 to be on top:

```
z-index: 999999;
```

You could just use a z-index of 10. I think your problem may be setting the z-index to negative. I think other elements z-index default to 0? So putting it to -1 could make it behind another element and causing a weird result.

Edit: just noticed you said your nav menu was absolute. So you would have to have a z-index for it. Instead of it being -1, change it to 10. Then for your image, change it to 20.. or 100.. anything higher.